# Relacionar elementos de una Lista de Objetos

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

No se si el titulo es el mas adecuado. Tengo un objeto que es una Lista de Objetos (extraido de una BBDD mediante JPA) el cual contiene 3 objetos que a su vez son Listas; 2 de tipo String y 1 de tipo Double. Para intentar ser mas exactos, serian code(String) volume(Double) y timestamp(String)

Controlo la estructura, la posicion de cada elemento es la correcta (el code de posicion 0 tiene volume de posicion 0 y timestamp de posicion 0)

Lo que no consigo encontrar es como, partiendo del code, sacar su volume y/o su timestamp. He buscado horas, quizas no con los terminos correctos, pero no he encontrado nada

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida

Gracias!

EDIT: Lo unico que tengo es una consulta JPA con un metodo el cual me devuelve 3 columnas de una tabla, y me los almacena en un objeto el cual he construido tal cual:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Calculo {

private String code ;
private Double volume;
private String update_timestamp;
}
```

El codigo restante seria algo asi

```
Calculo listaObjetos = claseDondeEstanLasQuerys.metodoQueTieneUnaQuery(param1, param2)
```

Donde code es una Lista de Strings, volume una Lista de Doubles y update_timestamp otra Lista de Strings

Por lo que, para ser exactos, sabiendo un update_timestamp, y sabiendo el code, sacar el volume que tiene ese code en ese update_timestamp, sacarlo como objeto o int o lo que sea para realizar operaciones con el. Espero haber sido explicito

Gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: Probaste con algunos Foreach anidados para llegar al objeto que necesitas iterar ?? Podrías poner algo de código así te podemos ayudar mejor !

Comment: Si son listas puedes anidar varios for o foreach y llegarás al elemento que buscas. Sin ver código... poco más se puede decir

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no es muy clara, el problema es recorrer la consulta o es obtener los datos?

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas gente, edito la pregunta a ver si me expplico mejor

Comment: Si son listas puedes usar un `Iterator` para recorrerlas